# unique_ptr inside a variant. Is it safe to use?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, variant

Id like to ask, is safe having a variant like this?

```
struct A
{
    unique_ptr<T> anything;
};
struct B
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
};
variant<A, B> myVar;

myVar = ... A object;
myVar = ... B object;
myVar = ... another A object;
```

Would the `std::unique_ptr` destructor be invoked for all compilers? The idea would be to create an `std::array` of `variant<A, B>` to use it in a FIFO. It seems working fine here in Visual Studio, but I ask because I read this from [cppreference.com/variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), and I'm not sure if I understood it fully:

> As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type T, the
> object representation of T is allocated directly within the object
> representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to
> allocate additional (dynamic) memory.

Comment: Yes, it's safe.

Comment: `Variant is not allowed to allocate additional (dynamic) memory.`

That does not reference the objects the variant holds, but the variant itself:
The object the variant holds is directly in the variant, not via dynamic allocation. It's a guarantee by the standard.

Comment: Yes. The very point of the variant class is to ensure proper destruction/construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paragraph you quoted is a guarantee by the standard;

> As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type T, the
> object representation of T is allocated directly within the object
> representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to
> allocate additional (dynamic) memory.

It means `std::variant` is *not* allowed to utilize dynamic allocation for the objects that the variant holds. It's a guarantee by the standard.

If you have a variant object with `Foo`, `Foo` is in the memory of the variant and not in a dynamically allocated object somewhere else.

Which means it is safe to use dynamic allocation (i.e. `unique_ptr`) within a variant. All destructors are properly called when they need to be called.